# Compatible change for WS consumers

Tags: soap, wsdl, field

We have SOAP services that are consumed by clients. We want to make changes to the service so that some of the existing fields that are currently char(20) we would like make them char(80). My understanding is that this is a compatible change and should not affect any existing SOAP Clients. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I would also assume that this will have no ill affects